# Basic react-cube-navigation example returns TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I want to create an instance of the react-cube-navigation component, found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cube-navigation).

However, when trying to run the given [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-cube-navigation-example-gngpz), React returns a TypeError:

```
TypeError: props.rotateY.to(function (x) {
        return "scale is not a function. (In 'props.rotateY.to(function (x) {
        return "scale(" + getScale(x, scaleRange);
      })', 'props.rotateY.to(function (x) {
        return "scale' is undefined)
```

And displays this block of code from the cube implementation:

```
  127 | return (React.createElement(animated.div, tslib_1.__assign({ className: "Cube", style: {
  128 |         width: width + "px",
  129 |         height: height + "px",
> 130 |         transform: props.rotateY.to(function (x) { return "scale(" + getScale(x, scaleRange); }),
  131 | ^       perspective: perspective + "px"
  132 |     } }, bind),
  133 |     React.createElement(animated.div, { className: "Cube__animated-container", style: {
```

I get a very similar error on Chrome and Firefox:

`TypeError: props.rotateY.to is not a function`

I know what the error message is saying, but I have no clue how to fix it. I believe there must be a fix that doesn't require diving into the cube implementation, since it works fine on codesandbox.

Could it have anything to do with version numbers? The dependencies on my system have different versions to the example on codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is related to version numbers.

I copied the version numbers from codesandbox and pasted them into my local package.json, then ran `npm install` and `npm start` and now it works.

So it could be that there is a bug in a new version of either react-cube-navigation or one of its dependencies, but it looks like I will be sticking with some slightly older versions for now.

Comment: Having same issue, but wasn't able to resolve it with setting to the same version numbers. Not sure what to do, I wonder if anyone else is experiencing this issue. Are you using NextJS, by any chance?

Comment: I'm not using NextJS. If all your version numbers match, then I'm not sure how else I can help, as this is what solved it for me.